# System.Reactive/Rx .NET 4.0 on Nuget

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0, system.reactive

I am trying to add `System.Reactive.Core` to a .NET 4.0 project using VS2013 and getting the following error:

```
Could not install package `System.Reactive.Core 3.0.0`. 
You are trying to install this package into a project that target 
`.NETFramework,Version=v4.0`, but the package does not contain any assembly 
reference or content files that are compatible with that framework.
```

I also cannot find the old Rx-Main packages anymore on `nuget.org`.

How can I get Rx Installed on .NET 4.0?

I guess I will have to manually go find the RxMain 2.x libs and reference them directly from a lib folder in my solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, Rx-Main has been unlisted, therefore can only install it using the following command:

`Install-Package Rx-Main -Version 2.2.5`

To Rx Team: You should of recreated 2.2.5 System.Reactive which allowed us to target .NET 4.0 before moving up to 3.0.0.

Comment: Yeah, they wrote about this as `breaking change`: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET

Comment: Yes, they put it out there that they renamed it, but not that 1. they removed .NET 4.0 support, and that the old library got unlisted, and to install you have to manually specify a version :-(

Comment: Yeah, that's bad from their side

Comment: For other Rx related packages, [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/de1a62fa-abe8-4ea3-a653-1ff47b4d8d82/reactive-extensions-assemblies-installers-and-nuget-the-full-story?forum=rx) could be useful.